# Pass node app.js variable to remote.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

We are creating a admin control webapp in node JS. 
Where admin can control user screen.

In admin area, Admin can select how many times a user can select video in 1 hour. Admin can change this any moment.

So we are capturing admin event with this code

```
socket.on('maxvideo', function(data) {
getUser( data.userid ).remotes.maxvideo=data.maxvideo;
});
```

And we have this code in user screen which is pure javascript. We want to capture this variable in user screen so we can add and modify validation any time ( Can change max video number any time ).

On user screen we wrote this code

```
server = io.connect();
server.on( 'maxvideo', function(data){
  console.log(data.maxvideo);
 });
```

But this is not working. 
Can anyone tell what we are doing wrong?

Comment: Do you ever send the message from server to client?

Comment: sounds like you need to emit the maxvideo event from the server back to the client socket. *Disclaimer* i know socket.io not remote.js they may abstract this.

Comment: New Comers should not be demotivated with negative, instead help them

Comment: I looked and the only "remote.js" i can find is about remote controlling things with a transmitter. Also why are you jumping into a users session when you can easily changed user settings server side.

Comment: Actually i am looking for something like this, But its not working in my app.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177070/nodejs-and-websockets-triggering-events